# append html elements as nested with angularjs javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a custom directive named `hero` And I want to create a nested view for multiple `heros`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10469/)

I want to get a view like this:

```
<hero a="1">
    <hero a="2">
        <hero a="3">
            <hero a="4"></hero>
        </hero>
    </hero>
</hero>
```

and controller is like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var elements = [
        angular.element('<hero a="1"></hero>'), 
        angular.element('<hero a="2"></hero>'), 
        angular.element('<hero a="3"></hero>'),
        angular.element('<hero a="4"></hero>')
    ];

    var content;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){

        if(!content){
                content = elements[i];
        }else{
                content.append(elements[i]);            
        }
    }

    console.log(content[0]);        
}
```

but it appears :

```
<hero a="1">
    <hero a="2"></hero>
    <hero a="3"></hero>
    <hero a="4"></hero>
</hero>
```

Comment: You missed an `content = elements[i]` after `content.append(..)`

Comment: I updated demo but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Full refactor of the idea exposed on the original answer.

You just need to keep "indexed" your last node so you can access to it and append the new (current) element to it. I show the relevant part of the code below.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    //... your code omitted for brevity

   var content;
   var eArr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){

        if(!content){
                content = elements[i];
        }else{
                elements[i - 1].append(elements[i]);
        }
        eArr.push(elements[i]);
    }

    console.log(content[0]);
}
```

Comment: Please, see my answer edited. With an [ief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) should work.

Comment: OK, let me check the demo. This seemed to be not so complicated. I'll give you feedback later

Comment: @bookmarker, I just edited my answer. See the new result gotten with this code. Sorry for the wrong previous answer. I tested this one and I got the result you said you needed.

Comment: Thanks for solution